# Filter function is not reutrning the original array

Tags: angular

I have a function in change event of 3 radio buttons: all, completed true and completed false. I want that when i click on completed true, the array should return only the items that have completed: true in them, and likewise for false. But what is happening is that when i click completed true first, and then click false, the false values doesnot appear because it is filtering from the already filtered true value, where it can find no false value.

html:

```
<input type="radio" value="All" [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioButtonValue" (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged('all')" />All

<input type="radio" value="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioButtonValue" (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged('true')" />Completed True

<input type="radio" value="false" [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioButtonValue" (change)="onRadioButtonSelectionChanged('false')" />Completed False

<table><tr *ngFor="let f of studentsfromapi | slice:0:10 | searchPipe:srchbytitle">
<td>{{f.userId}}</td>
<td><a [routerLink]="['/student-details', f.id]">{{f.id}}</a></td>

<!--<td><a routerLink="['/student-details/{{f.id}}">{{f.id}}</a></td>-->
<td>{{f.title}}</td>
<td>{{f.completed}}</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

ts:

```
selectedRadioButtonValue:string;


  onRadioButtonSelectionChanged(e):any{


        if(e=='all'){
    console.log("studentsfromapi:::"+this.studentsfromapi);
     // return f.title.indexOf(args.toLowerCase())>-1
     //return this.studentsfromapi.indexOf(e.toLowerCase())>-1

    }

    else if(e=='true'){

      //this._StudentHttpServService.getstudentHttpSrv().subscribe((employeeData) => //this.studentsfromapi=employeeData );
      console.log('true');
      this.studentsfromapi = this.studentsfromapi.filter(x=>x.completed.toString()==e.toLowerCase() && x.id<5 );

    }

    else if(e=='false'){

      //this._StudentHttpServService.getstudentHttpSrv().subscribe((employeeData) => //this.studentsfromapi=employeeData );
      console.log('false');
      this.studentsfromapi = this.studentsfromapi.filter(x=>x.completed.toString()==e.toLowerCase() && x.id<5 );

    }

      }
```

here, `studentsfromapi` is the valriable that is returning all arrays. so i am using filter function on `this.studentsfromapi` Array is coming from this:

service file:

```
 export class StudentHttpServService {

  constructor(private _http:Http) { }

  getstudentHttpSrv(): Observable<IStudentHttp[]>{

return this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
.map((response:Response) => <IStudentHttp[]>response.json());

  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Create 2 instance of the array and filter only from the original of that.

Comment: can you show me the code?

Comment: Do you want to download new results or just filter elements on the client side?

Comment: my current requirement is for client side, but it would be great if you show me for both..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, you use **filteredResult** everytime so **studentsfromapi** won't be affected.

```js
//this is original array
var studentsfromapi = [{"id":1,completed:true,name:"test"},{"id":2,completed:false,name:"test1"},{"id":3,completed:true,name:"test2"}];
var filteredResult = [];

filteredResult = studentsfromapi.filter(a=> a.completed);

console.log(filteredResult);
filteredResult = studentsfromapi.filter(a=> !a.completed);
console.log(filteredResult1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

problem is in this line

```
this.studentsfromapi = this.studentsfromapi.filter(x=>x.completed.toString()==e.toLowerCase() && x.id<5 );
```

you should use different array for filtered items

```
filteredStudentsFromApi = [];

this.filteredStudentsFromApi = this.studentsfromapi.filter(x=>x.completed.toString()==e.toLowerCase() && x.id<5 );
```

and use filteredStudentsFromApi in HTML